# My Wi-Fi on ubuntu 16.04 xenial xerus often disconnect and DNS error

Tags: networking, 16.04, kernel

How do I correct my wifi? All my friends in office have stable connection, only me that often disconnect and DNS Error.

I already try:
WIFI regulatory domain not set

Set the WIFI country code for the Kernels current regulatory domain if it isn't set.

iw reg get
To set it

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
REGDOMAIN=<ISOCODE>
```

Reboot.

Upstream kernel
my kernel is `4.8.0-36-generic`

My hardware is Lenovo G40
i3

ubuntu architecture type 64bit

is it my office wi-fi router? or my ubuntu? because when I use windows it don't have problem..

Thank You

[SOLVING]
go to Network Connections and then Edit your ethernet interface. change the tab to IPV4 Settings and set DNS in Additional DNS Servers field like 8.8.8.8.

I use google public DNS and restart my wifi network it seems alright now. I will update the condition if this just false answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the DNS must set to google DNS because my internet provider have DNS problem, so just change DNS in network configuration to

```
8.8.8.8

8.8.4.4
```

and it work normally again.